# Why can't I access a "$:" aka reactive variable inside the script tags in svelte3?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, reactive-variable

I am pretty new to svelte started it a week ago......

I am trying to know about it i really loved❤️❤️ it but I have a problem☹️☹️

I am trying to access a $: variable in the script tags but i get an Error `Cannot access 'greeting' before initialization`.

```js
<script>
    let name = 'world';
    $: greeting = `Hello ${name}`
    console.log(greeting)
</script>

<h1>Hello {name}!</h1>
```

I also tried declaring the variable with **let** prior to using it

```js
    let greeting
```

But in this case `console.log` outputs `undefined`.

Comment: Please add text as *text*, not screenshots.

Comment: I will add text from the next time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution to your problem is to make the `console.log(greeting)` statement reactive as well:

```js
<script>
    let name = 'world';
    $: greeting = `Hello ${name}`
    $: console.log(greeting)
</script>

<h1>Hello {name}!</h1>
```

Because `console.log` is not a reactive statement in your example, it is actually executed *before* any reactive statement, following the 'normal' flow execution of your script. So when it is executed `greeting` has not yet been set (your first error) or it has been set to `undefined` through the `let greeting` declaration (your second error).

By making `console.log` reactive, you ensure it will be executed (a) *after* `greeting` has been set (which solves your first issue), and (b) *every time* `greeting` is set (which solves your second issue). And you do not have to declare `greeting` prior to assigning it a value in a reactive statement.

Comment: Thanks Thomas ... It is working!!! 